# Python Error, Local Variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, local-variables

```
tries= 3
for i in range(3):
    username=input("What is your username ")
    if username =="student":
    
        
        pwd=input("Whats your password ")
        if pwd=="password":
            print("welcome")
            studentname=input("What is your full name? ")
            studentage=input("What age ar you ")
        
    f = open('data.txt', 'wb')
    f.write("Student = " + str(studentname) + "\nAge = " + str(studentage))
    f.close()
```

And when i enter the username it will say:

```
f.write("Student = " + str(studentname) + "\nAge = " + str(studentage))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'studentname' referenced before assignment
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please properly format your code to match your actual indentation. `studentname` won't be set though if `pwd=="password":` is false.

Answer (score 1):

`studentname` and `studentage` aren't defined unless password is correct. I made to modifications to your code to improve it:

1. I put it in a `while True` statement so you need correct password to contiue
2. I defined `studentname` and `studentage` 100% of time.

```
while True:
    pwd=input("Whats your password ")
    if pwd=="password":
        break
print("welcome")
studentname=input("What is your full name? ")
studentage=input("What age ar you ")
f = open('data.txt', 'wb')
f.write("Student = " + str(studentname) + "\nAge = " + str(studentage))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe because you're password is not correct, I think it is better to use an else statement as :

```
if pwd=="password":
    print("welcome")
    studentname=input("What is your full name? ")
    studentage=input("What age ar you ")
    
    f = open('data.txt', 'wb')
    f.write("Student = " + str(studentname) + "\nAge = " + str(studentage))
    f.close()
else:
    print('Password is wrong')
```